# Lighttpd rewrite rule

Tags: lighttpd, rewrite

Why does a rewrite rule like this not work:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^parameter/(.*)$" => "/somefunnyfile.php?someparameter=$1"
)
```

... but a rule like this does work:

```
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^/(.*)$" => "/somefunnyfile.php?someparameter=$1"
)
```

This is the mimed Apache RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^acraproxyphp/(.*)$ acraproxy.php?reportid=$1
```

Comment: Can you give us some example URLs here? On the surface the string "parameter" would be my guess that it's not matching your URLs, but without them I can't say for sure.

Comment: Most likely because of the missing `/`

Comment: @frostschutz Missing where?